# Matching 2 elements inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

Let's say that I have a class Person

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, sign, likes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sign = sign;
        this.likes = likes
    }
}

var a = new Person("Jim", "virgo", "piscis");
var b = new Person("Sara", "sagitarus", ["piscis", "sagitarus"]);
var c = new Person("Sam", "aries", "Leo");
```

This class describes their Zodiac sign, and what are their favourite zodiac signs.

Then, I have an array of people:

```
var people = [a, b, c, ....]
```

What I would like to achieve is, starting from the beginning of the array, to find the first possible match, based on their sign and what they interests are.

For instance:

- if the first item in the array is a person with sign **Aries interested in persons with sign Virgo**, search the array for the first person with the sign **Virgo that is interested in Aries**.
- if the first item in the array is a person with the sign **Aries interested in Virgo**, but **noone in the array is a Virgo interested in Aries**, then proceed to try to match the next person in the array.
- if the first item in the array is a person with sign **Aries interested in persons with sign Aries**, search the array for the first person with the sign virgo that is interested in Aries, **but excluding himself**.

What I expect to get is:

- both the persons matched
- the same array of persons, but with those 2 erased from the list

Something like this:

```
var match = matchPair(my_people_array);
// match is an array of 2 Persons
// match is falsy in case of no matches
// my_people_array is 2 items shorter (or a new array, not necessary to modify the original array)
```

I tried to solve it yesterday for a long time, but I could not come with any solution even close to working.

How could I achieve this result in JS?

**UPDATE**

Since I do not want to give the impression that I did not try anything by myself first, here is the best I could come up with, even though I know it is not working:

```
function match(people) {
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        var person = people[i];
        var match = people.find((candidate)) {
            return candidate !== person && candidate.likes.includes(person.sign) && person.likes.includes(candidate.sign)
        }

        if (!match) return false

        return [person, match]
    }
}
```

While this gets me some matches, I also keep getting people matched in more than 1 group

**UPDATE 2:**

I will put some exanples to see if the idea is more clearly explained

```
// CASE 1

var persons = [
    new Person("Jim", "virgo", ["aries"]),
    new Person("John", "aries", ["virgo"])
    new Person("Justin", "aries", ["piscis"])
];

matchCouple(persons)
// returns an array with Jim and John
// "persons" contains Justin only

// CASE 2

var persons = [
    new Person("Jim", "virgo", ["virgo"]),
    new Person("John", "virgo", ["virgo"])
];

matchCouple(persons)
// returns an array with Jim and John
// Beware not to pair Jim with himself
// "persons" is empty

// CASE 3

var persons = [
    new Person("Jim", "virgo", ["aries"]),
    new Person("John", "piscis", ["virgo"])
];

matchCouple(persons)
// returns falsy value
// persons does not change

// CASE 4

var persons = [
    new Person("Justin", "aries", ["piscis"]),
    new Person("Jim", "virgo", ["aries"]),
    new Person("John", "aries", ["virgo"])
];

matchCouple(persons)
// returns an array with Jim and John, skipping Justin because he had no matches
// "persons" contains Justin only
```

Comment: Looks interesting to spend some minutes to solve this, however I think it's not worth it because you didn't try anything.

Comment: A little off-topic, perhaps, but I'd suggest making the 'likes' argument the same type in all cases, whether a white-space separated string or arrays of strings. It makes it a little easier to put together a solution if you don't have to test for argument types.

Comment: I would use a switch statement to check for the different signs for each index in the people array

Comment: Then [edit] your question to show your best effort[s], explain where those efforts failed, what *should* have happened and what did, or did not, happen instead. We're here to help you with your code, not write the code for you; and we can't help your code if we can't see it.

Comment: I updated the question with my code. Please remove the downvote.

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes I am going to use some kind of "enum" to define the types, but I want to start simpler.

Answer (score 1):

here we reduce your array of people and find a match based on the first person in the original Array's star-sign (`ss`) against the persons `likes`

```js
let people = [
 {ss: 'aries', likes: 'virgo'},
  {ss: 'cancer', likes: 'scorpio'},
  {ss: 'virgo', likes: 'aries'},
  {ss: 'scorpio', likes: 'virgo'},
  {ss: 'cancer', likes: 'virgo'},
  {ss: 'sagitarius', likes: 'sagitarius'}
]

const CREATE_MATCH_ARRAY = () => {
 let matches = people.reduce((pre, person, i, orig) => {
   pre.push([person, orig.find(p => person.likes === p.ss)])
    return pre
  }, [])
  
  return matches
}

console.log(CREATE_MATCH_ARRAY())
```

An issue i can for-see is your `people` Array to have unique identifiers so that if a person object looks like `{ss: 'aries', likes: 'aries'}` doesnt end up matching with itself.

Let's see what we can do.

```js
let people = [
 {ss: 'aries', likes: 'aries', ID: 1},
  {ss: 'cancer', likes: 'scorpio', ID: 2},
  {ss: 'virgo', likes: 'aries', ID: 3},
  {ss: 'scorpio', likes: 'virgo', ID: 4},
  {ss: 'cancer', likes: 'virgo', ID: 5},
 {ss: 'aries', likes: 'cancer', ID: 7},
  {ss: 'sagitarius', likes: 'sagitarius', ID: 6}
]

const CREATE_MATCH_ARRAY = () => {
 let matches = people.reduce((pre, person, i, orig) => {
   pre.push([
      person, 
      orig
      .filter(p => p.ID !== person.ID)
      .find(p => person.likes === p.ss)])
    return pre
  }, [])
  
  return matches
}

console.log(CREATE_MATCH_ARRAY())
```

Code to handle multiple `likes`

```js
let people = [
 {ss: 'aries', likes: 'aries', ID: 1},
  {ss: 'cancer', likes: 'scorpio', ID: 2},
  {ss: 'virgo', likes: 'aries', ID: 3},
  {ss: 'scorpio', likes: ['virgo', 'aries', 'cancer'], ID: 4},
  {ss: 'cancer', likes: 'virgo', ID: 5},
 {ss: 'aries', likes: 'cancer', ID: 7},
  {ss: 'sagitarius', likes: 'sagitarius', ID: 6}
]

const CREATE_MATCH_ARRAY = () => {
 let matches = people.reduce((pre, person, i, orig) => {
   let filteredOriginal = orig.filter(p => p.ID !== person.ID)
   pre.push([
      person, 
      filteredOriginal
      .filter(p => p.ID !== person.ID)
      .filter(p => {
       if (Array.isArray(person.likes)) {
         return filteredOriginal.filter(p => person.likes.indexOf(p.ss) !== -1)
        }
        else {
         return person.likes === p.ss      
        }
       })])
    return pre
  }, [])
  
  return matches
}

console.log(CREATE_MATCH_ARRAY())
```

Comment: Please notice that "likes" can also be an array of signs.

Comment: The option of the uids already came to my head, but I would like to see if there is an option without them.

Comment: Maybe by comparing indexes of the people in the array during the reduce

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make this simple by creating methods that work both ways?

```js
const convertToArray = val => typeof val === 'string' ? [ val ] : val;

class Person {
  constructor(name, sign, compatibleSigns) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sign = sign;
    this.compatibleSigns = convertToArray(compatibleSigns);
  }
  likes(otherPerson) {
    if (otherPerson == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return this.compatibleSigns.indexOf(otherPerson.sign) > -1;
  }
  isLikedBy(otherPerson) {
    if (otherPerson == null || otherPerson.compatibleSigns == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return otherPerson.compatibleSigns.indexOf(this.sign) > -1;
  }
  isCompatible(otherPerson) {
    return this.likes(otherPerson) && this.isLikedBy(otherPerson);
  }
  likesSelf() {
    return this.likes(this);
  }
}

var a = new Person("Jim", "virgo", ["sagitarus", "piscis"]);
var b = new Person("Sara", "sagitarus", ["piscis", "sagitarus", "virgo"]);
var c = new Person("Sam", "aries", "Leo");

console.log(a.likes(b));        // True
console.log(a.isLikedBy(b));    // True
console.log(b.isCompatible(a)); // True
console.log(b.likesSelf());     // True
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: While the methods `likes`and `isLikedBy` work, they do not account for the person liking himself. Also the management of the array of people is also a big part of my problem.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Not sure what you mean, but I updated the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use find and filter to help, and check for match both ways.

Here's an example:

```js
    class Person {
        constructor(name, sign, likes) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sign = sign;
            this.likes = likes
        }
    }

    var a = new Person("Jim", "virgo", ["piscis"]);
    var b = new Person("Sara", "sagitarus", ["piscis", "sagitarus"]);
    var c = new Person("Sam", "piscis", ["sagitarus"]);

    var persons = [a, b, c];

    // helper methods
    var isLikedBy = function(person1, person2) {
      return person1.likes.indexOf(person2.sign) >= 0;
    };

    var findMatch = function(persons) {
      for(var x in persons) {
        var person = persons[x];
        var match = persons.find(function(p) {
          if(p == person) return false;
          return isLikedBy(person, p) && isLikedBy(p, person);
        });
        if(match) {
          return [person, match];
        }
      }
    }

    // find the match
    var match = findMatch(persons);
    if(match) {
      persons = persons.filter(function(p) {
        return match.indexOf(p) < 0;
      });
    }

    console.log(match, persons);
```

Comment: But this code does not solve my problem of removing the persons from the array of persons, or how to scan the whole array for all possible matches

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to go through the array and get a list of all possible matches, right? What this does is it goes through the whole array, removes the person itself that we are testing, and for each candidate match it checks if the likes are both ways. Is the output of running the snippet not the expected? Can you provide sample input and sample output?

Comment: I do not want a list of "possible" matches. I want to make a match, with the first possible pair.

Comment: we can use find instead of filter then! will change, and we can then give it a spin.

Comment: You take manually the first person to be matched, `b`. I need to go through the array until finding someone that I can match, skipping the ones that are not matchable.

Comment: So given an array, you only have to find the first possible match, going through each person in order, check their likes, and then see if any of the ones she likes has a match in the array.